# How to make the 'setInterval' run in start moment

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Below code, will delay 10 second then execute the function A and B first time.

```
setInterval(function () {
    A();
    B();
}, 10000);
```

I wanna execute A and B at the program run at the same time. Like,

```
A();
B();
setInterval(function () {
    A();
    B();
}, 10000);
```

There is no better way to do it?

---

Thanks all.

Comment: you want them to run once when the program loads? what does it mean at the same time?

Comment: make the function execute them, then setTimeout(self,10000) in the tail

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function

```
var fnc = function(){
 A(); B();
};
window.setInterval(fnc,10000);
fnc();
```

Or use setTimeout

```
(function x(){ A(); B(); window.setTimeout(x, 10000);}())
```